# Determine the minimum value of: $P=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{(x+y)^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2+yz+z^2}}{(y+z)^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+zx+x^2}}{(z+x)^2+1}.$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $x,y,z>0$ satisfy $x+y+z=\dfrac{3}{2}$.Determine the minimum value of:
$$P=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{(x+y)^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2+yz+z^2}}{(y+z)^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{z^2+zx+x^2}}{(z+x)^2+1}.$$

I have tried:

$\bullet$ The minimum value is $\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$ occur when $x=y=z=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$  \bullet P\ge \dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(x+y)}{(x+y)^2+1}+\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(y+z)}{(y+z)^2+1}+\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(z+x)}{(z+x)^2+1}$

$\bullet$ So we need to prove $\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(x+y)}{(x+y)^2+1}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ as well as prove $\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(y+z)}{(y+z)^2+1} \ge \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(z+x)}{(z+x)^2+1}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$

$\bullet$ Let $a=x+y$, the problem is $\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a}{a^2+1}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ or $\dfrac{-(a-1)^2}{a^2+1}\ge0$ (which isn't true)

Pls help me with this problem and it would be nice if you could explain why my work is wrong.

Comment: You may change $x,y,z>0$ to $x,y,z\ge 0$ in case the minimum occurs when one of $x, y, z$ is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum does not exist.

Let $x\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}^-$ and $y=z\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, we get a value $\frac{12}{13}.$

We'll prove that it's an infimum.

If it's given that $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $z\geq0$ so for $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{3}{2},0,0\right)$ we obtain a value $\frac{12}{13}$ again

and we'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, let $x=\max\{x,y,z\}$.

Thus, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^2}}{(x+y)^2+1}\geq\frac{x+\frac{y}{2}}{(x+y)^2+1}+\frac{x+\frac{z}{2}}{(x+z)^2+1}+\frac{\frac{5}{6}(y+z)}{(y+z)^2+1}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(x+\frac{y}{2}+x+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{5}{6}(y+z)\right)^2}{(x+y)^2\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)+(x+z)^2\left(x+\frac{z}{2}\right)+\frac{5}{6}(y+z)^3+2x+\frac{4}{3}(y+z)}=$$
$$=\tfrac{\frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)\left(2x+\frac{4}{3}(y+z)\right)^2}{(x+y)^2\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)+(x+z)^2\left(x+\frac{z}{2}\right)+\frac{5}{6}(y+z)^3+\frac{8}{9}\left(x+\frac{2}{3}(y+z)\right)(x+y+z)^2}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\tfrac{\frac{2}{3}(x+y+z)\left(2x+\frac{4}{3}(y+z)\right)^2}{(x+y)^2\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)+(x+z)^2\left(x+\frac{z}{2}\right)+\frac{5}{6}(y+z)^3+\frac{8}{9}\left(x+\frac{2}{3}(y+z)\right)(x+y+z)^2}\geq\frac{12}{13}$$ or
$$303(y+z)x^2+4(43y^2+248yz+43z^2)x\geq(y+z)(104y^2-35yz+104z^2),$$
which is obvious

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: If $x=\dfrac{3}{2}$ so $y=z=0$ because $x+y+z=\dfrac{3}{2}$ but $x,y,z>0$ ?

Comment: @Thiên Phạm Huỳnh  It should be $x\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}^-$ and  $y=z\rightarrow0^+$. I fixed.

Comment: If the condition is $x,y,z\ge0$, do you think the minimum exists?

Comment: @Thiên Phạm Huỳnh Yes, of course.

Comment: Although it seems a bit annoying, can you do the case with the condition $x,y,z\ge0$ ? I would appreciate it if you help me

Comment: @Thiên Phạm Huỳnh I added something. I hope now it's clear.